# Why can't I use the maximum 40 votes in a single day?

Tags: support, badges, voting

To earn the [Vox Populi badge](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/64/vox-populi) a user must cast "the maximum 40 votes in a day." I notice that no one has earned this badge.

Recently I used 39 votes in one day. Further attempts to vote gave me the "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in # hours." message. The same thing has happened to me today, only this time I have only used 36 votes. I note that today some of my votes were on comments (rather than questions/answers) and two of my votes today were down votes.

Is there any known reason why I can't use all 40 votes?

Comment: I hit the cap yesterday, but I didn't notice my count, I assumed it was 40.  I didn't get the badge either.

Comment: I just got the badge.

Comment: sonovagun!..!!!

Comment: Sad, I got another 39 votes today. Maybe miscounted answer votes. I still had one vote on a comment though, and I am still wondering if that eats a vote.

Comment: Yay, I got the badge today! Okay, I promise I'll stop posting on this thread now. (for a while at least :P)

Comment: yes. me as well, the 40 hit and badged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only achieve the full 40 votes in a day if at least 10 of those votes are for questions.

Your ability to vote stops once you vote for 30 answers.   If you vote for 5 questions and then 30 answers, you cannot vote any more until the next day.

Comment: Please see the screen shots in my updated answer.  I can't vote for anything.

Comment: @mrc that is indeed possible if you don't vote for 10 questions before reaching the end.

Comment: so the cap stops if I hit 30 answer votes?  Meaning if I vote for 5 questions, then 30 answers I'm done? I can't vote for more than 35 times that day?

Comment: @alex that is correct

Comment: I updated the answer with the details from the comment thread.

Answer (score 8):

See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/

The old limit used to be 30 votes.   Now, you can vote 40 times in a day, but only if you vote on questions and answers.

Are you voting on questions also?

Comment: Yeah I'm voting on a combination of questions, answers and comments. Mostly questions and answers. Not counting comments at least 1/3 of my votes are on questions.

Comment: After you hit the limit of 30 [by any combination of voting], you can only vote additional 10 on questions only.

Comment: Just to test it out, I voted 40 times today and got the badge.

Comment: Not true that the *last* 10 votes have to be on questions. My 39th and 40th votes today were for answers, but as Jeff notes in another answer, I had at least 10 question votes earlier in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I am having the same problem.  Did somebody start at 0?  It has been about 20 minutes since my last vote, and it still reads 39.

**EDIT**

This screen shows me voting for an answer, but it would be the same if I voted for a question after a good nights sleep.

[image]

Here I am voting for a question:[image]

These screen shots are also revealing I am a maniac for this site I think.

Comment: Try voting for a question and not for an answer, it should do the trick

Comment: That isn't it.  I just tried a new question since I posted this and I cannot.

Comment: See JeffAtwood's answer and the comments underneath for clarity.

Comment: I deed, I deed.  My edits were in before his, but I got it now.  I don't like it, but what is a digital sharecropper to do?  =)